# Laravel scout lazy loading

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I'm using Laravel scout for searching my entire site. So when someone search for a message I return this:

```
public function messages($search)
{
   return Message::search($search)->paginate(4);
}
```

But now I've to send the related forum aswel. Already tried this:

```
public function messages($search)
{
    return Message::search($search)->load('forum')->paginate(4);
}
```

That does not work. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only give you this workaround at the moment. You could load forum data manually:

```
$messages = Message::search($search)->paginate(4);
$forums = Forum::whereIn('id', $messages->pluck('id'))->get();

return compact('messages', 'forums'); // Return an array of messages and related forums.
```

Comment: That will throw an exception: ```Call to undefined method Laravel\Scout\Builder::with()```

Comment: Thanks for helping. It throws an error again: ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::search()```

Comment: @Jamie I can't give you a better solution right now, but I've added some workaround. `Forum` part code is related to the type of relationship between `Message` and `Forum` models.

Comment: Thanks for helping did it like this: ```return Message::search($search)->paginate(4)->load('forum');```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$message = Message::search($query)->paginate(25); 
// while this returns a Collection, it also updates the $message Paginator.
$message->load('forum');
```

`$message` will be the result now.

You get the data on the paginator... more details here.
https://gist.github.com/Artistan/fea3e21f149fdf845e530299bcff37d4

Comment: your method returns collection instead of paginated results.

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas - details here..
https://gist.github.com/Artistan/fea3e21f149fdf845e530299bcff37d4

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel Scout with tntsearch, and this how I solve the problem.

```php
$ids = Message::search($search)->keys()->toArray();
$messages = Message::with('forum')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```